# Is there any way to pass a php variable which will be 'hidden' even if user check source code of my page?

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

when i use a code like,

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo $var;?>" />
```

the $var is displayed in source code of my web page. is there any way i can hide that variable from my users seeing in my source code by using PHP/Codeigniter? am using codeigniter for my project.

in short, what i want to do is send data to a controller when a form is submitted. but not through url or hidden html input fields

Comment: I guess you'll have to pass through the value by using sessions.

Comment: You can encrypt a hidden value.

Comment: It looks as if CI has an encryption library.  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: Does it matter if people see the value/variable?

Comment: Thanks for your replys guys. Both sessions and encrypting will do the job. I feel sessions work better for my project. Anyway thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use codeigniter's session library to store data which won't be visible in source code.

- Session library need to be loaded (`$this->load->library('session');` or autoload in `application/config/autoload.php` )
- In your controller set the data what you want to store (`$this->session->set_userdata(['your_secret_data_key' => 'your_secret_data_value']);`)
- You can retrieve your data (`$this->session->userdata('your_secret_data_key');`)

So before you generate the form add the data, and in the controller which will process your form you can retrieve the previously stored data.

More info about the session library: [Codeigniter's session library documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I feel This solution will be more practical as i have to deal with sessions already in my code. Also ecrypt and decrypt wont do the work as other can decrypt easily. Anyway thanks a ton for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use encryption library to encrypt this value before you send it to the view and upon retrieving it decrypt it again.

Loading the library: `$this->load->library('encryption');`

you can find more details in the documentation about its configurations.
[encryption](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)

```
$var = 'value';
$var = $this->encryption->encrypt($var);
$this->load->view('view', array('var' => $var));
```

Now you have an encrypted `$var`, do whatever you have to do and upon retrieval you can just use this:

```
$var = $this->encryption->decrypt($var);
echo $var;    // value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i feel like setting session and destroying after use will be more helpful as anyone can decrypt my encrypted data.

Comment: @Rishad, it would be pretty pointless encryption if anyone could decrypt it.  You'll be the only one with the key.

Comment: @Rishad, the question errs towards having some payload in the user submitted form.
_"i want to do is send data to a controller when a form is submitted"._
Sessions may be an alternative workaround for you.  But sessions can dangle somewhat, you've a tight coupling to server side transient data that way.